# Autowiring MongoClient and MongoClientSettings without explicitly specifying a Connection String

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am upgrading the MongoDB driver which requires moving away from the older `MongoClientOptions` to the newer `MongoClientSettings`.

In the older implementation, the following configuration was used within a @Configuration class with the ConnectionString inferred from the `spring.data.mongodb.uri` and an `@Autowired MongoTemplate`:

```
@Bean
public MongoClientOptions mongoOptions() {
        Builder clientOptionsBuilder = MongoClientOptions.builder()
                //Timeout Configurations
                if(sslIsEnabled) {                  
                    clientOptionsBuilder.sslEnabled(true) 
                    //Other SSL options
                }
        return clientOptionsBuilder.build();    
    }
```

And in the Newer Implementation, a ConnectionString parameter is specifically expected, and the property file `spring.data.mongodb.uri` is not selected automatically. As a result, I have specified the connection string using the `@Value` Annotation. Not doing this results in the program to infer `localhost:27017` as the connection source.

```
@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
String connectionString;

@Bean
public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    MongoClientSettings.Builder clientSettingsBuilder = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyToSocketSettings(builder -> {
                // Timeout Configurations
            }).applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(connectionString));
    if (sSLEnabled) {
        clientSettingsBuilder.applyToSslSettings(builder -> {
            builder.enabled(sslIsEnabled);
            //Other SSL Settings
        });
    }
    return MongoClients.create(clientSettingsBuilder.build());
}
```

While documentation and other StackOverflow posts mention MongoClientSettings overrides the property file entries, is there a way to retrieve/infer the MongoClientSettings from the property files and then append other custom configurations to it?

I am using Spring Boot 2.6 and spring starter dependency for MongoDB

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that a similar question asked on GitHub earlier.

[Modify MongoClientSettings while using auto configuration with mongodb #20195](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20195)

Replacing the `@Bean` configuration which had `MongoClientOptions` with `MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer` helped solve the problem.

```
@Bean
public MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer mongoDBDefaultSettings()
        throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    return builder -> {
        builder.applyToSocketSettings(bldr -> {
        //Apply any custom socket settings
        });
        builder.applyToSslSettings(blockBuilder -> {
        // Apply SSL settings
        });
        // Apply other settings to the builder.
    };
}
```